# pycharmで作成したファイルがpythonのファイルとして認識されない。

Tags: python, pycharm

以下に示した画像の通り、フォルダplactice_1を右クリックして、New→python fileの作成手順で"lesson.py","lesson_2.py"というファイルを作成しました。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

しかし、上のlessonというファイルはpythonのファイルとして認識されておらず(pythonのアイコンが表示されていないため、そのように判断しています。)、デバック等が行えません。（画像参考、下のファイルではRunやdebugが表示される）

このファイル名をlesson以外のファイル名にリネームするとpythonのアイコンが付きます。
例えばlesson→eessonなどに変更するとPythonのアイコンが付く、この時拡張子などはいじっていない。

なぜこうなってしまうのか原因がわかる方いましたら教えてください。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 原因についてはさておき、こちらの [ファイルタイプをすばやく変更する](https://pleiades.io/help/pycharm/creating-and-registering-file-types.html#quickly-change-file-type) で対象を指定してpythonのファイルとして設定できませんか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

下記の操作で再現しましたので設定を確認してみてください。

`File`メニュー > `Settings...` > `Editor`ツリー > `File Types`

- `Recognized File Types`の`Text`行をクリック

  - `Registered Patterns`に`lesson.py`や`lesson*`が含まれていないこと
- `Recognized File Types`の`Python`行をクリック

  - `Ignore files and folders`に`lesson.py`や`lesson*`が含まれていないこと

[PyCharm not recognizing Python files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11687302/8248751)

[image: PyCharm]

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
少し違う操作でしたが、大変参考になる回答でした。本当にありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

解決しました。
ご回答いただいた内容とは異なり、私のバージョンでは、
`File`>`Setting`>`Editor`>
`File types`>`Recognized File Types` >`File name patterns`
からlesson.pyを消去したら、所望の動作をしました。
ありがとうございました。
※PyCharm 2021.2.1 (Community Edition)
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]